# XNA Framework Giving Error that No suitable graphics card found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, graphics, xna, parallels

I am running Parallels desktop in Mac to use Windows 7 to learn Game Designing and Development using C# and XNA Frame Work, so I installed Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and XNA Game Studio 4.0 and just simply created a new Game Studio project and tried to run it in the Parallels Desktop but that gives me an error :
[image]

In the 3d acceleration I have given `DirectX10` and my Mac's system information is :

```
Processor: 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5
Memory   : 4GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Graphics : Intel HD Graphics 4000 1024 MB
Software : OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
```

Please tell me is there any solution to this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Intel HD 4000 graphics card only works in the 'Reach Profile' setting. Not in the HiDef setting as it is lacking some features required for that. Please see this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/12/reach-vs-hidef.aspx

You can change the project to the 'Reach Profile' like this:

[image: Reach]

Comment: It doesn't work, I get the same error, only difference is that it mentions Reach profile any other solution??? @Roy

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved the problem, as I was using Parallels Desktop, I simply had to install the Parallel's tools for the virtual machine, so after installing that, it even worked nicely with HiDef Profile.